# CEPH S3 Exception while Listing Blobs

Tags: kubernetes, ceph, rook-storage

I have created an S3 bucket backed by CEPH and through java S3 client and via S3 object gateway am listing the directory in a paginated fashion and randomly the listing is failing some times after listing 1100 blobs in batches, some times after listing 2000 blobs in batches and am not able to figure out how to debug this issue, this is the exception am getting and if you notice there is a requestId in the exception I think basis this I can filter the logs but where can i find the logs is the question, I have checked the s3 gateway pod logs but I couldn't find any such logs over there, please let me know where should I look for the same

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: null (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 500; Error Code: UnknownError; Request ID: tx00000000000000000e7df-005e626049-1146-rook-ceph-store; S3 Extended Request ID: 1146-rook-ceph-store-rook-ceph-store), S3 Extended Request ID: 1146-rook-ceph-store-rook-ceph-store
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1799)
```

and this is my code to iterate through the blobs, this is non paginated, the paginated version, both the versions are throwing the same exception after listing few hundred blobs

```
  ObjectListing objects = conn.listObjects(bucket.getName());
        do {
            for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objects.getObjectSummaries()) {
                System.out.println(objectSummary.getKey() + "\t" +
                        objectSummary.getSize() + "\t" +
                        StringUtils.fromDate(objectSummary.getLastModified()));
            }
            objects = conn.listNextBatchOfObjects(objects);
        } while (objects.isTruncated());
```

So, any pointers on how to debug this would be helpful.. Thanks

Comment: I tried with boto as well immediately after listing 2000 keys, it's failing with botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnknownError) when calling the ListObjects operation (reached max retries: 4): Unknown

Answer (score 0):

Try ListObjectV2.

> Returns some or all (up to 1,000) of the objects in a bucket.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html